# Create a trigger update

Tags: postgresql

Create a trigger that automatically when inserting data into the builds_result table updated the value of the updated_time field of the apps table to the current date and time. Error is given in on apps.updated_time

`create trigger upd after insert
on builds_result
for each row 
execute procedure new apps.updated_time = now();`

Comment: This sounds more like an instruction (to you) rather than a question for us.

Comment: @eurotrash the fact of the matter is that I tried to write but every time it gives a syntax error

Comment: Post the code then so we can try to see what's wrong. And post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: I think you need to have a read of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html to see the correct way to create a trigger, and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html on how to create a trigger function.

Comment: This results in an error indicating apps.updated_time
`create trigger upd after insert
on builds_result
for each row
execute procedure new apps.updated_time = now();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief overview of how to setup a trigger.

First create the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE apps
    SET updated_time = NOW();

    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It's very simple, just updates the table (notice it will update all records, this is simply because you haven't said which particular record should be updated) and returns `NEW`, which is the record that was inserted in `builds_result`.

Then you create a trigger on the `builds_result` table to execute this function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd
    AFTER INSERT ON builds_result
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_function();
```

That's it. Now that trigger function will be called every time a row is inserted into the `builds_result` table.